# Lock camera on an axis?

Tags: camera

How do I lock the camera on an axis in Blender? For example I want the camera to not rotate at all, but only slide perfectly parallel to X or Y axis. This way I can check if one of my objects is centred or not to the parent object.

Comment: The camera or the viewport?

Comment: Oh I meant viewport. Like how to snap to a particular axis?

Comment: Use numpad, `Num 1`, `Num 3` and `Num 7`. Use `Ctrl` to invert

Answer (score 5):

To align the viewport to a specific axis you can use the Numpad:

- `Y` axis - <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>
- `X` axis - <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>
- `Z` axis - <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in conjunction with these keys to invert the direction you are looking along the axis. To move along a certain axis while preserving your viewport orientation:

- To move along the `Z` axis - hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while scrolling.
- To move along the `X` or `Y` axis - hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while scrolling.
- To zoom along the `X` or `Y` axis - scroll.

Comment: If you have a fourth mouse button I strongly recommend binding it to translate directly, much easier to not accidentallyrotate then imo. I need to look up how to do that in blender natively though; I did mine with autohotkey back before 2.5. (mouse5 is zoom selected, default num period i think, for me.)

Answer (score 2):

You can lock the rotation of your camera by locking the rotation axes in the transform panel.

For moving your camera on a local axe you can press 'G' and 'X' twice to move on the local X axe of your camera

[image: rotation lock]